Minimizing and Maximizing functions using gurobi
I'd like to know if there is a way to optimize multiple functions using gurobi, like can I maximize a function and minimize another? I'm trying to maximize the probability of a service to not fail while trying to restore and minimize the number of hops that a service will use to restore. I already tried to minimize the probability of failing but is not working. In this case I'm writing a lp file for the optimization.
